# How to build a ListView with TextView and two ImageButtons

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

In Android, I want to build a ListView containing all items like the following skeleton:

[image]

The **Soundname** part (textview) changes according to the loaded string's array (a list of sound names).
The two **ImageButtons** have always the same icon and must play or select the sound corresponding to the item clicked.

At the moment I only know how to build a ListView with one Textview and inflate it through an Adapter loading the String's array.

Can you give me some example code on how to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Look for custom listview in google

Comment: check this : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: Simply *Google* it.

Comment: "Do my job" question

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom Adapter by extending the `BaseAdapter` and set it as your list's adapter. Look for a tutorial online like [this one](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow these steps
1-Create main xml file with listview
2-Create another xml file with name list_itmes with textview, and with both image button
3-Now Write code in your Activity 
a)create listview object
b)Here we need to use BaseAdapter it has some methods inside getView() inflate another xml file as follows


public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = items;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDesc;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);

        holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {     
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relInfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="SoundName"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgOne"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/images" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgTwo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgOne"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/images" />
</RelativeLayout>
```